# Create a convex Polygon from unordered vertices

Tags: python, polygon, voronoi

**Short version:**
Given: Vertices of a convex 3d-Polygon
Looking for: The edges connecting the vertices, s.t. the Polygon is convex.

**Long version:**
I started with a bunch of 3d-points and calculated the [voronoi tessalation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) using [this function from the scipy.spatial package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html). I'm actually are looking for the right edges to get the polygons created by it, but I do not understand how the package does it.

At the moment I just figured out how to get the vertices and to which polygon they belong, but knowing the vertices of a polygon alone would not be enough to recreate it unless I'd get the edges. So how do I get them? Is there maybe a simple way to do it or even better: a package which does it for me?

Since I know it must be convex I had an idea for the 2d-case (basically just circling around the centre (the mean) of the polygon and connecting the vertices following each other), but I don't know if this approach would work in 3d or if it would even create a convex polygon. I also think this approach would be probably not reliable and/or take a lot of time to compute.

I can supply code if wanted, but I don't think it would help.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, perhaps this will be of help: [scipy.spatial.ConvexHull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html).

Comment: Thanks, that looks really promising.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [bb1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15187728/bb1) for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191090/python-create-a-convex-polygon-from-unordered-vertices/66205476#comment117021943_66191090) :)
`scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` does the job. (Technically it didn't work 100%, but I think that might be a different problem which occurs in 3d.)